# installing sharepoint 2013 using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I know there's a way to install SharePoint 2013 via powershell. Does anyone have any scripts you recommend for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely awesome tool called [AutoSPInstaller](https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/).

Allows you to automate installation of SharePoint farms from 2010 to 2016 versions, automatically applies updates, custom database names and many many more. Check it out.